# Textbox gone hide under keyboard in my webview Android app

Tags: android, xml, webview

This is my androidmanifest.xml activity code:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in all activity tag in MeniFest file

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
 android:name="com.apnabanaras.ShowWebView"   
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscr‌​een"/>
```

and remove this line

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscr‌​‌​een">   it shows can not resolve symbol in android studio

Comment: remove that line

Comment: If you don't want toolbar in your activity then write this line in activity tag  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: remove that line from your xml

Comment: i don't know how to share pic...can you tell me

Comment: click edit and click on image icon then browse your image

Answer (score 0):

test this attribute:

```
<activity
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
 android:name="com.apnabanaras.ShowWebView" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscr‌​‌​een">
```

Comment: hey...this is my activity in android manifest.... is there any need to change anything it<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:name="com.apnabanaras.ShowWebView"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">

Comment: <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:name="com.apnabanaras.ShowWebView" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscr‌​een">

Comment: @Shailesh: please delete your comments here containing code, and **edit your question**. I have tried to add code formatting, but it seems some code is missing. Please move the code in your comments into your question.

Comment: I have tried to add code formatting, but it seems some code is missing.